# Error 405 when trying to make an Ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-status-code-405

Good afternoon. I am having a problem sending a route using Ajax The problem is as follows.  I have an HTML form that contains a selection of employees.  What I intended was that when I selected an employee, Ajax would return me the positions concerning him.  I had done something similar before, but this error had never occurred.

**JS**

```
 $('#funcionario').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'teste',
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'id' : $('#funcionario').val();
                },

            }).done(function(e){
                alert("success->"+ e)

            }).fail(function(){
                alert('Deu ruim')

            })
    })
```

**Route**

```
Route::POST('teste', function() {
    return 1;
});
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: try using lowercase for the route method `Route::post(//...)`

Comment: tentei mas não funcionou

Comment: please, write in english. you have https://pt.stackoverflow.com for portuguese speakers

Comment: I managed to solve. I added in the  url do ajax 'main_url + "/ route" ' and it worked. Anyway thank you

Comment: Good job. Please, post the answer and mark it as resolved when you can, so other users can look upon it.